# Christian Gnostisicim and Sufism

Tags: christianity, sufism

I've been reading on [Gnostisicism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnosticism) and I found it similar to Sufism to some extend. To me,
it's very probable that early Sufis were  influenced by Gnosticism to some degree. Given that, did any Sufi scholars wrote on the subject of Gnosticism, compared/contrasted it with Sufism ?

Comment: I'd doubt this, especially as anything related to Christianism might be easily declared as kufr. While Sufi's say their practice is that of "Ihssan احسان". On the other hand Gnosticism itself had many different influences some even coming from Persia.